# Opening a file as pop up in MyWebsite

Tags: javascript, html, file, google-docs

I am developing  a website where user can upload multiple files (pdf,doc,xlsx....)
later i display the available files list to user ...When he/she clicks on the file name i want to open the file as a popup.

What I  tried  using iframes 
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://example.com/files/pages.doc

I am getting nothing..Can anyone  Provied exact way to do it??`

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://example.com/files/pages.doc" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

`

Comment: Maybe use javascript to open the local file in a popup window? `window.open("file://mylocalfile.pdf", "Preview", "width=500,height=500");`

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a link to the document like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/files/pages.doc">Open document http://example.com/files/pages.doc</a>
```

And let the browser work out how to launch it, it will either use a viewer, or launch an app to display it

Comment: I want to open file using google docs viewer (different file extensions)

Comment: It should be a simple link to a document. If it's in Google docs, there will be an id for it https://docs.google.com/document/XXXXX/view, or are you trying to open an external document using google docs?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://docs.google.com/a/nasonline/viewer?url=http://www.nasonline.org/publications/biographical-memoirs/memoir-pdfs/einstein-albert.pdf